# How to derive the distribution of an orthogonal projection of a degenerate random vector representing a circle?

Tags: integration, probability-distributions, self-learning, dirac-delta, change-of-variable

I am studying to develop an ability to derive distributions of transformations of [random variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_variable), especially when the dimension of the input doesn't equal the output dimension of change of variables. [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Vector_to_scalar) gives this description for a mapping $V:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$:

> Let $V:\mathbb{R}^n \mapsto \mathbb{R}$ be a differentiable function and $X$ be a random vector taking values in $\mathbb{R}^n$, $f_X$ be the probability density function of $X$ and $\delta (\cdot)$ be the Dirac delta function. It is possible to use the formulas above to determine $f_Y$, the probability density function of $Y=V(X)$, which will be given by $$f_Y(y) = \int_{\mathbb{R}^n}f_X(\mathbf{x}) \delta (y - V(\mathbf{x}))d\mathbf{x}.$$

I want to explore the case of having a degenerate random vector and derive the density of the 1-dimensional output by simply dropping variables. Suppose we have $$\mathbf{x}(t) = \begin{bmatrix} \cos t \\ \sin t \end{bmatrix}$$ with density $$f_X(\mathbf{x}) = \delta (\cos t) \delta (\sin t)$$ and $$V(\mathbf{x}(t)) = \cos t$$ then $$d\mathbf{x} = d(\cos t) d(\sin t) = - \sin t \cos t\ dt\ dt$$ and (with some simplification done by SymPy) we have

$$f_Y(y) = - 2 \pi \int\limits_{0}^{2 \pi} \sin{\left(t \right)} \cos{\left(t \right)} \delta\left(y - \cos{\left(t \right)}\right) \delta\left(\sin{\left(t \right)}\right) \delta\left(\cos{\left(t \right)}\right)\ dt.$$

Neither I, SymPy, or Wolfram alpha can solve this integral. It has occurred to me that $V$ is an [orthogonal projection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projection_(linear_algebra)#Orthogonal_projection), but I don't know if knowing that helps any. I'm not even completely sure that the answer is actually a density function, but it looks like it could be:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns

t = np.arange(0, 2*np.pi, 1/10**4)
x, y = np.cos(t), np.sin(t)

sns.jointplot(x=x, y=y, s=1)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Is there a way to proceed with deriving the distribution in this example?

---

SymPy code:

```
import sympy as sp

t = sp.Symbol('t', real=True)
y = sp.Symbol('y', real=True)

fx = sp.DiracDelta(sp.cos(t)) * sp.DiracDelta(sp.sin(t))
q = sp.DiracDelta(y - sp.cos(t))
dx = sp.diff(sp.cos(t)) * sp.diff(sp.sin(t))


I = sp.integrate(sp.integrate(fx * q * dx, (t, 0, 2 * sp.pi)), (t, 0, 2 * sp.pi))
```

---

This is what the contour plot of the integrand looks like according to Wolfram Alpha:

[image]

[image]